# Could not receive GCM when app was closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, google-talk

I made an application which is receiving GCM message from my server. I tried to implement as google's sample (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-receive). It worked normally unless the issue. That is if I killed my app in memory, my broadcast receiver will never receive GCM message.
I tried to get logs of device and see that this issue is regarding GTalkService:

```
01-15 14:19:40.509: W/GTalkService(1300): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.paktor (has extras) }
01-15 14:19:40.750: W/GTalkService(1300): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.paktor (has extras) }
01-15 14:19:41.090: W/GTalkService(1300): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.paktor (has extras) }
```

My receiver is in manifest.xml:

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"  >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.paktor" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Updated:
My broadcast:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(this, "Receive GCM message");
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

And permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I don't know why. Every thing look like normally. Please help me know how to catch GCM message when my app was killed.

Comment: I think you need to see WakeLocker in android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: I added android.permission.WAKE_LOCK It's not problem

Answer (score 0):

Make **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** like this

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

also **permission**

```
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: I implemented like this before. I guess it's not problem

Answer (score 0):

set `delay_while_idle=0` when sending gcm message